# MongoDB group by year and class then count - not working

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

Trying to create the mongo-like version of:

```
SELECT class,year(event_datetime), count(*)
FROM db
GROUP BY class, year(event_datetime)
```

I thought this ought to do it but its not working:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([{$group :{_id : "$class",year: {$year :"$event_datetime"}}},{count : {$sum : 1}}])
```

How can I rewrite this so it will work?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

Both group by fields (`class` and `year`) should be inside `_id`, and then count total documents,

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        class: "$class",
        year: { $year: "$event_datetime" }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```